# How to use UUID in sveltekit route?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have `./routes/jobs/[id].svelte`

an example "id" would be: "456d7bb6-9dc5-49a3-8700-566b34c38829"

this doesn't seem to work with sveltekit.

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import Jobs from '$api/jobs';
    import User from '$api/user';
    import { goto } from '$app/navigation';
    import { page } from '$app/stores';

    let job = {};

    onMount(async () => {
        console.log('id: ', $page.params);
        job = await Jobs.getById($page.params.id);
    });
</script>
```

I get the following error instead:

```
404

Not found: /jobs/456d7bb6-9dc5-49a3-8700-566b34c38829

Error: Not found: /jobs/456d7bb6-9dc5-49a3-8700-566b34c38829
    at resolve (file:///home/user/www/example-ui/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/ssr.js:1682:10)
    at async svelteKitMiddleware (file:///home/user/www/example.com/example-ui/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/chunks/index.js:4538:22)
```

Comment: Don't see anything wrong right away. Are you using a page endpoint that is throwing a 404?

Comment: my bad. i had the file in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 2):

Correct file for such route is `./routes/jobs/[id]/+page.svelte`.

`[id]` should be a directory where you can put `+page.svelte +layout.svelte ...`