# SvelteKit: $api build-in module

Tags: sveltekit

I've seen a code using $api module, but after looking into the docs I found no mention about this module there. So does this module realy exist or could it be some kind of custom module?

There is where I saw the code: [How to use UUID in sveltekit route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71797472/how-to-use-uuid-in-sveltekit-route)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just an [alias](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-alias) to some directory, not a built-in module. Just like [`$lib`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$lib) references a specific directory one can add other such aliases.

SvelteKit has its own configuration for [adding additional aliases](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/configuration#alias).